# ruby: libraries, frameworks, servers providing concurrency for development of a web based chat

Tags: ruby, web-applications, concurrency, chat, nonblocking

What ruby concurrency lib/framework should I use for the development of a web based chat?

I have read about Eventmachine and Celluloid *libraries*, and about Sinatra::Synchrony, Cramp, Goliath and Gserver *concurrency-ready-servers*. If I am getting this right, all these libs or servers implement concurrency using two main different approaches: the reactor pattern (mostly all of them), or the use of multithreading (i.e. gserver, ...).

Now if this is all correct, and I hope it is, could someone:

- correct me if it is not...
- point out other actively developed libraries or frameworks that I've missed ?

The reason I am asking this is that I am trying to build, for learning purposes, a web based chat using ruby on server side. It will interact with client using websockets or Server Side Events, with Jquery or something else.

Also I've read about using ruby with a Xmpp server, or pub/sub messaging system (like Faye). If I put one of these in the dish, am I correct if I say if that it all shrinks down to having to worry only about making requests to those servers in a non-blocking way, rather than having to set-up a complete "non-blocking" ruby chat server ?

I know this is a bit convoluted, but I hope it still make sense.. 
But in case I am going totally the wrong direction about something, can someone please give me at least a general, vague idea of what I need to understand better ?

Thanks!

Comment: "At the *present time*" makes this too localized. "*Most* active" makes it not constructive. Please read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: Changed the question to address a more specific problem and removed the "too localized" and "non constructive" parts. Could you reopen it please?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall Could you re-open the question please? There are new things coming out in ruby world in these days regarding the very topic of my question, and it'd be interesting to hear as many opinions as possibile. Also if you missed it, I tried to rework the question in a non localized and constructive way. Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place for open-ended discussion or receiving people's opinions. Please thoroughly read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny you should ask. Peter Cooper from Ruby Weekly mentioned (Issue 116 - October 25, 2012) a [talk](http://www.slideshare.net/KyleDrake/hybrid-concurrency-patterns) subtitled "Ruby developers need to stop using EventMachine. It's the wrong direction," which spawned some interesting debate on [HN](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4695828), since many frameworks are built on top of it (Goliath, Cramp, etc.)

The disenchanted flock either to Celluloid (with Sidekiq as its most famous client), to the  Node.js platform or to other languages that offer solid concurrency primitives from the get go. Yes, Go, Erlang, Clojure...

Personally, I implemented a realtime web-based chat not long ago using Cramp, Redis Pub/Sub and Websockets, loosely adapted from the following [demo code](https://github.com/lifo/cramp-pub-sub-chat-demo). It worked as advertised,   but the traffic it gets doesn't compare to the requirements of some high volume systems elsewhere.